# Sharepoint Workflow setup

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

Newbie to sharepoint but this thing didnt work for me as expected.

I am trying to have a sharepoint form:

1)Where accounts fills in section (presses submit, email sent to IT to fill in their section)
2) IT gets email, go fill in their section(press submit, email to MD to approve /reject)
3) MD approves/rejects
4) data saves

I have the form working, and using views am able to go between forms.

Issue is how
1)email alert to groups
2)half filled forms, given to other groups

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To Solve your first problem :
You can create an event reciver which will fire when an item is created in the list as well as when an existing item is changed in the list Or you can also create a workflow for this too.

There is an approval workflow OOTB which may be helpful for you too, but i am not sure about that.

For the Second question :

Whenever you open the existing item again, infopath form will automatically manage the data entered in the form and displays it as filled data.

Hope this helps.